# Multi-input function surjectivity and injectivity

Tags: functions

How does surjectivity and injectivity apply to multi-input (multivariable) function?
Let say we have a function `from R x R to R`:

> f(x,y) = x + y + 6

If we assume that f(x,y) = 9, so:

> 9 = x + y + 6

And thus:

> 3 = x + y

So does it mean that the function is not injective for pairs x,y (for example) `f(1.5, 1.5)` and `f(0, 3)` as both are giving the same output equal 3? Or is it not working that way?

And in terms of surjectivity, `if x, y ∈ R and f(x,y) = z` , function will be surjective if the output will simply be `z ∈ R`?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is surjective if for every element of the codomain, say $z$, there exists an element of the domain whose image is $z$. In this case, $f$ is surjective since for each $z \in \mathbb R$ we have $f(z,-6) = z$. The injectivity part is fine!